# C++ functions and scope of variables

Tags: c++, function, scope

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

void fun(int a) {
    int x;
    cout << x << endl;
    x = a;
}

int main() {
    fun(12);
    fun(1);
    return 0;
}
```

The output of this code is as follows:

```
178293 //garbage value
12
```

why are we getting `12` and not garbage value instead??

Comment: Those who play with uninitialized variables and undefined behavior are doomed to suffer.

Comment: What is the value of `x` when you `cout<<x<<endl;`?? (perhaps move `x=a;` to the top of the function??)

Comment: `12` is a garbage value (one of many)

Comment: It's undefined behavior. The second time around the garbage value happens to be 12.

Comment: `x` is un-initialized. put `x = a;` before `cout` statement.

Comment: `12` is as garbage as any other value. Call a different function in between that uses the stack and you will probably see something else. Just because it is what you expect doesnt mean that it is correct

Comment: It's UB. With a different compiler, different optimization level, on a different platform or even just on the next run you could get different results. You are not guaranteed anything and *anything* is allowed (including compiling your program to nothing or causing it to summon demons).

Comment: @JesperJuhl • if using Visual Studio, and the undefined behavior summons demons, please file a defect report with Microsoft.  Although the behavior is allowed by the standard, Microsoft would prefer to fix that situation as there may be some negative public relations repercussions.

Comment: seriously just don't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> why are we getting 12 and not garbage value instead??

In theory, the value of `x` could be anything. However, what's happening in practice is that two calls to `fun` one after the other is responsible for the previous value of `x` to be still on the stack frame.

Let's say the stack frame is structured as below:

```
 arguments
 return value
 local variables
```

In your case,

Memory used for arguments is equal to `sizeof(int)`.
The compiler may omit using any memory for the return value since the return type is `void`.
Memory used for local variables is equal to `sizeof(int)`.

When the function call is made the first time, the value in the arguments part is set to 12. The value in the local variables is garbage, as you noticed. However, before you return from the function, you set the value of the local variable to 12.

The second time the function is made, the the value of the argument is set to 1. The value in the local variable is still left over from the previous call. Hence, it is still 12. If you call the function a third time, you are likely to see the value 1 in the local variable.

Anyway, that's one plausible explanation. Once again, remember that this is undefined behavior. Don't count on any specific behavior. The compiler could decide to scrub the stack frame before using it. The compiler could decide to scrub the stack frame immediately after it is used. The compiler could do whatever it wants to do with the stack frame after it is used. If there is another call between the calls to `fun`, you will most likely get completely different values.

Comment: The stack frame could be jettisoned into a black hole, twenty million years before the program is even executed.

Answer (score 0):

You have not initialized the value `x` when printing it. Reading from uninitialized memory is UB, *i.e.*, there are no guarantees as to what will happen. It could output a random number, or invoke an unlikely combination of bits that will do something unexpected.

Answer (score 0):

Reading an uninitialized integer is `UNDEFINED BEHAVIOR`, that means that it can do literally anything, can print anything. It can format your hard drive or collapse the observable universe! Basically I dont know compiler implementations that do so but theoretically they can!

Comment: You never know!